How to access JWT in Blazor server after login?
I'm calling an API for authentication from a Blazor server project. The API responds with a JWT.
I'm able to save it after login in a ProtectedLocalStorage like this
await protectedLocalStorage.SetAsync("authToken", result.Data.Token);

And I've added a CustomAuthenticationStateProvider in order to read the token & add it to all requests' DefaultRequestHeaders like this
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    ProtectedBrowserStorageResult<string> token;
    var anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    try
    {
        try
        {
            token = await _protectedBrowserStorage.GetAsync<string>("authToken");
        }
        catch
        {
            token = new();
        }

        if (!token.Success)
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(anonymous);
        }

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Replace("\"", ""));
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(token.Value), "jwt");
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        return new AuthenticationState(anonymous);
    }
}

And I'm able to delete it for logout like this:
await protectedLocalStorage.DeleteAsync("authToken");

I noticed that after login, GetAuthenticationStateAsync always gets called twice where the 1st time _protectedBrowserStorage is null & the 2nd time it has the correct value.
The problem is that when I go to any page after login, _protectedBrowserStorage comes as null in GetAuthenticationStateAsync
I need to know why after login GetAuthenticationStateAsync gets called twice. I assume the 1st time it's called, it's very early in Blazor lifecycle because I get this exception

JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time

And the 2nd time it's called after Blazor is ready to access it.
More importantly, I need to know how to access the token for all the pages after the login. I know the token exists but I'm not able to access it

The problem you are facing is probably caused by prerender. JSinteroop is not accesbile while prerendering the page thus, protectedLocalStorage is null because it relies on JS.
I always disable prerendering so I do not need to deal with it. It' s annoying so it's best to split your app into 2 part. The one for not logged users (promo page/ contact page etc.) and actual app that needs your state.
On the other hand you could implement your own logic for error handling and dealing with preload.

Thanks but even if I split it into 2 parts, I still need to authenticate the "actual" app using JWT, so how can I achieve this?

The simplest way is to disable prerender on components that use Authentication. For global disable make it like this :     <Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)" />  You can always change prerender on individual components. I have also seen other approach. You check if component is after first render (Use blazor function OnAfterRender and bool parameter iSFisrtRender).  When this method is inovoked Js is loaded and it is safe to use protectedlocalstorage .   Create your component enclosed by if(IsAftrerFirstRender). Hope this help.

Thanks, disabling prerender & calling the API to GET data OnAfterRenderAsync solved it for me
